# SQL Server Parallelism - never happens

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the 64-bit dev version of sql server.

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011
>   00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

My main table has 600k records. I routinely select from this and have many (more than 6) subquerys in the select while also self joining to the same table. Some queries take up tp 15 mins. Yet I have never seen sql server use more than one processor.

[In this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913180/how-do-i-make-use-of-multiple-cores-in-large-sql-server-queries) there is a list of questions, my queries fill ALL those questions. "Do you have a multi-core machine?" Really ? That's a question?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094(v=sql.90).aspx
Yes I have "Max Degree of Parallelism" = 0.

So my request is can someone create a script that proves parallelism works on their machine.

Im hoping for something like.

- create 2 tables
- auto fill them with ids and some garbage
- select from both tables , use sub queries, sorts, groups, whatever to demonstrate parallelism.

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This results in a query with parallelism for me:

```
USE master

SELECT o1.object_id, o1.type
INTO #temp
FROM sys.objects o1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects o4

SELECT o1.type, o2.type, COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM #temp o1
JOIN #temp o2 ON o1.object_id = o2.object_id
GROUP BY o1.type, o2.type
```

Comment: Im shocked to hear that. WhenI run it on my machine it take milliseconds and only uses one core (as expected). Anyone got an example with an redonkulous amount of records so I can clearly see it woprking?

Comment: Here you go (see my edit). Takes 40s for the first query and the 2nd one took 130s. Look at the actual execution plan. This is a ton of data for any machine.

Comment: I'm not sure that Sql Server uses Parallelism just because you have many cores. AFAIK Sql Server uses it when it sees fit. In your case Sql Server thinks that the cost won't improve by using parallelism. Parallel execution does not mean less cost and less time. Depending on the load of the server it usually means the contrary.

Comment: I can assure you that a) the query runs in parallel for me (Core i7, 16GB RAM) and b) it is well suited for parallelization. If this does not trigger parallelism the server does not support it for one reason or another. Maybe look at the cost threshold for parallelism - the default is 5.

Comment: tuzac is correct. All the docs Ive read say the execution planner guesses the single vs multi core time as part of its plan. If multi core won't provide significant benefits its ignored. That's what I think is happening in my case.

Comment: in reply "to usr". As I said that query takes mill-seconds on my machine and the planner will decide to run it on a single cpre

Comment: Still hoping for a script that'll demo multi-core.

Comment: @user2201214 The script in this answer gives me a parallel plan. Can you post the actual execution plan XML for when you run it?

Comment: @user2201214 I edited my post at the time of my fist comment here. I guess you did not notice the change. (I just increased data size). Only the 2nd query is parallel.

Comment: I tried it again ,you're correct it does run in parallel. My queries must be "unparralliseable".

Comment: If you open a new question and post the query and actual execution plan there I'll take a look. (Plz post the question link here).